# Randomly assign NA values to a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

I'm trying to assign NA values to a column.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
           V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
           V3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
df
```

How can I assign 2 NA (10*0.20) values to 'V1'? After this process, a data set will be generated. I want to repeat this process 10 times. The data sets generated after each replication must be different from each other. At the end of the day, I will have 10 data sets to export.

Comment: There are 45 ("10 choose 2") possibilities, so if you do this at random, about 80% of the time all ten data sets would come out distinct. Is it an actual requirement they be distinct or just an expectation?

Comment: You are right @JonSpring All 10 data sets obtained must be different from each other.

Comment: Are you planning to scale this to larger data sets and more missing values?  The `combn` approach probably won't scale, whereas repeated random sampling will.

Comment: Yes @CPB, I'm planning to scale these codes to larger data sets (1000 rows; 10%, 20%, 30% missing values; 20 or 40 columns; 1000 replication). Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scalable approach which should be relatively efficient:

```r
n.rep <- 10
n.na <- 2
# stores NA indices which have been used already
na.ind.used <- character(n.rep)
lapply(seq_len(n.rep), \(i) {
  repeat {
    # candidate indices
    na.ind <- sample.int(nrow(df), n.na)
    # string representation of indices for comparison
    na.ind.str <- paste(sort(na.ind), collapse=' ')
    if (!(na.ind.str %in% na.ind.used))
      break
  }
  na.ind.used[[i]] <<- na.ind.str
  df$V1[na.ind] <- NA
  df
})
```

Theoretically, we could also enumerate all possible combinations, randomly select from their indices and generate the combinations with these indices directly without any testing for duplicates. However, with large data we might run out of integers for the enumeration and would need a larger data type and at the moment I don't think it's worth the hassle.

---

*Original approach which doesn't scale well. With larger data (1000 rows, 10% or more of missing values leading to 6.385051e+139 or more combinations), this approach is not possible:*

To do this effectively, I would use `combn` to generate all possible pairs of indices for the two `NA` values and then randomly choose 10 of these:

```r
set.seed(0)
ind <- combn(nrow(df), 2)
ind <- ind[, sample.int(ncol(ind), 10)]
apply(ind, 2, \(i) {
  df$V1[i] <- NA
  df
}, simplify=F)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7  NA  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[2]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[3]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6  NA  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[4]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[5]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[6]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[7]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[8]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4  NA  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[9]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8  NA  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[10]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7  NA  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign NA's by position using `[<-`

```
X <- sample(1:10,2) # creates length 2 sample of integers without replacement
df[[1]][X] <- NA # only positions defined by X are NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `repeat`edly `replace` *m* `sample`d positions and check if `!anyDuplicated`.

```
> n <- 10L
> m <- 2L
> res <- vector(mode="list", length=n)
> set.seed(42)
> for (i in seq_len(n)) {
+   repeat {
+     res[[i]] <- transform(df, V1=replace(V1, sample.int(n=length(V1), size=m), NA))
+     if (!anyDuplicated(res[seq_len(i)])) break
+   }
+ }
> stopifnot(!anyDuplicated(res))
> res
[[1]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[2]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[3]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4  NA  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[4]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[5]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7  NA  1  1
8  NA  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[6]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4  NA  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[7]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4  NA  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[8]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[9]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[10]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5  NA  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), V2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), V3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
lapply(
  sample(
    combn(nrow(df), 2, simplify = FALSE),
    10
  ),
  \(k) {
    df$V1[k] <- NA
    df
  }
)
```

which could give you something like

```
[[1]]
   V1 V2 V3
1  NA  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[2]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10 NA  0  1

[[3]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4  NA  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[4]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7  NA  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[5]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8  NA  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[6]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7  NA  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[7]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8  NA  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[8]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[9]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2  NA  0  1
3   0  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6  NA  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  0
10  0  0  1

[[10]]
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  1
3  NA  0  1
4   1  1  0
5   0  1  0
6   1  1  0
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9  NA  1  0
10  0  0  1
```